# ¿Porque el resultado de lo siguiente en php es 3?

Tags: php, php7

Estoy realizando un tipo test con mis compañeros y no entiendo el motivo de porque devuelve 3. Quien me lo puede explicar y muchas gracias de antemano. Saludos

```
<?php 
    $a = array("A","B",1 => "C","D", 2=> "E" );
    echo count($a);
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si pones esto:

```
var_dump($a);
```

Verás en la salida lo que está ocurriendo:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "A"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "C"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "E"
}
```

Lo que ocurre es que ese array tendría **dos veces** un valor para el ìndice `1` y para el índice `2`. Un array no puede tener dos o más veces un mismo índice, en cuyo caso el array se quedaría **con el último valor encontrado**, como bien dice el [Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.array.php):

> Si varios elementos en la declaración del array usan la misma clave,
> sólo se utilizará la última, siendo los demás sobrescritos.

Por tanto, en tu array, los valores `B` y `D` son sobre-escritos por los valores `C` y `E`.

Es importante señalar que los arrays asumen índices, lo indiques o no en su construcción. Es decir que hacer esto por ejemplo:

```
$a = array("A","B","C","D","E");
```

Es como hacer esto:

```
$a = array(
             0=>"A",
             1=>"B",
             2=>"C",
             3=>"D", 
             4=>"E" 
          );
```

Aunque no lo indiques explícitamente, PHP asignará a cada valor un índice, partiendo desde `0`, en el orden en que están puestos los elementos.

Supongamos que tú indicas índices explícitos o implícitos en cada valor, pero sin colisiones, verás que entonces sí es tomado en cuenta cada valor:

```
$a = array("A", 3=>"B", 1=>"C", 4=>"D", 2=>"E" );
var_dump($a);
```

**Salida:**

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "A"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "B"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "C"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "D"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "E"
}
```

En el código anterior, PHP asignó para `A` el índice `0`, aunque no indicaste índice para dicho valor, y para los otros valores, asignó los ìndices explícitos que indicaste.

Y si indicas dos o más veces un mismo índice, aún de forma explícita, el array final se quedará con el último de esos índices repetidos:

```
$a = array("A", 1=>"B", 1=>"C", 4=>"D", 2=>"E");
var_dump($a);
```

**Salida:**

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "A"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "C"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "D"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "E"
}
```

En el código anterior, se asignaba explícitamente un índice `1` para el valor `B` y para el valor `C`, y `B` fue sobre-escrito por `C`, tal y como indica la documentación citada más arriba.

Comment: muchas gracias nos ha ayudado mucho

Comment: Me alegro de haberte ayudado a resolver tu problema @JavierG.Raya. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Buen día.

Esto pasa porque utilizas la función `count` por defecto (normal) la misma no toma en cuenta la multidimensionalidad de un arreglo, en cambio, la función recursiva sí, aparte tienes un error de sintaxis cuando tienes más de un arreglo con la función flecha seguido de otro arreglo, como lo tienes toma un índice un valor, en cambio, si le dices array te respeta la multidimensión.

Aquí el código:

```
<?php

$a= array("A","B", 1=>array("C","D"), 2=>"E");

echo count($a); // Normal --> Resultado 3
echo "\n";
echo count($a, COUNT_RECURSIVE); // Recursivo --> Resultado 5

?>
```